# Find Ingress IP in Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

## What I have:

I have difficulty setting up an Ingress with Helm Chart on the cloud.

- I have a project with a Front, a Back and a MySQL database.
- I setup two Ingress, one for my **BackEnd** and one for my **FrontEnd**, I can access it with an IP given by **Google Cloud Platform**.

In the **FrontEnd** and **BackEnd** charts `values.yaml`:

```
...
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 8000 # 4200 for the FrontEnd
  targetPort: 8000 # 4200 for FrontEnd

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-ConSSH / 51970trol,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
  hosts:
    - paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
...
```

## My Issue:

The **FrontEnd** needs to talk to the **BackEnd** throughout the Ingress.
In the **FrontEnd** values.yaml, I need to have a value:
`BACKEND_URL: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000`
But I don't know the URL of the **BackEnd** Ingress, or at least, until I deploy the back.

- How can I variabilize it, to retrieve the URL ingress of the **BackEnd**?
- Or at least, how can I find the ingress IP? (I've tried kubectl get ingress, it doesn't show the address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Don't use the ingress but the service DNS name. This way your traffic doesn't even leave the cluster. If your backend service is called `api` and deployed in the `backend` namespace you can reach it internally using `api.backend`. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns has details about the mechanism.
2. You reserve the IP on GCP side and pass the IP as a parameter to your helm charts. If you don't, each deletion and recreation of the service will end up on a different IP by GCP. Clients who have a cached DNS response will not be able to use your service until it has expired.

For GCP this snippet from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) is correct.

> Some cloud providers allow you to specify the `loadBalancerIP`. In those cases, the load-balancer is created with the user-specified `loadBalancerIP`. If the `loadBalancerIP` field is not specified, the loadBalancer is set up with an ephemeral IP address. If you specify a `loadBalancerIP` but your cloud provider does not support the feature, the `loadbalancerIP` field that you set is ignored.

So get a permanent IP and pass it as `loadBalancerIP` to the service.

```
  service:
    spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      port: 8000 # 4200 for the FrontEnd
      targetPort: 8000 # 4200 for FrontEnd
      loadBalancerIP: <the Global or Regional IP you got from GCP (depends on the LB)>
```

Comment: I need the ingress for one reason, the annotations, especially the CORS allow annotation, I can not modify the backend code, so I have to use an Ingress, I will try to obtain a static GCP IP and set it like you said.

Comment: you're not actually answering the question about how to get it from helm. you're getting it outside of helm and passing it in. presumably helm has this information as well.